# How to fix incorrect date and time of laravel when updating date and time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I currently have problem regarding incorrect date and time inserting on my database, I currently use laravel and in my app.php the **'timezone' => 'Canada/Central',** today I insert an order which my time and date is 11:23PM / 09/06/2019 then after I insert the order in database the order_date is incorrect based on my time.

**My Time and Date:**

[image]

**Order date and time Inserted in database:**

[image: order_date]

**I will share to you guys my script and code:**

```
$now = new DateTime();

DB::insert('INSERT INTO order_properties (customer_id,order_ship_address,delivery_status,order_ship_province,order_date,transaction_number) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?) ',[

        $hidden_customer_id,
        $hidden_customer_address,
        'Processing',
        Auth::user()->manager_location_assign,
        $now,
        $sessionTransactionNumber


    ]);
```

Comment: did you try by clearing config cache. just run `php artisan config:clear` as well as clear cache `php artisan cache:clear`. most of the time whenever we change something in configuration. we need to restart our server (`php artisan serve`). so laravel know about new changes

Comment: yes I already did that on our server. but i got wrong time and date.

Comment: also instead of using php datetime you can use `'now'` in its place if your column format is datetime or timestamp. also check your mysql timezone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql)

Comment: I insert today 11:52PM then in my order_date column its 6:00:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have used the timezone during setting time. Else preferred to use the Eloquent for the data insert.

PHP `DateTime` class would not read the laravel settings automatically.

Also I would suggest to keep timezone in .env file so it could be accessible across the application. Here is what you can do for this.

1. Add new key `APP_TIMEZONE` in .env

   `APP_TIMEZONE="America/Chicago" //change as per your timezone.`
2. Update `config/app.php` to use .env settings.

   `"timezone" = env("APP_TIMEZONE", "UTC");`
3. You must use the `Carbon` library and change code to fetch timezone like

   `$now = Carbon::now(env("APP_TIMEZONE"));`

Also make sure your timezone `Canada/Central` must be available in php supported list.

Here is the timezone supported by PHP https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp

Comment: do you know how to use multiple app timezone,?? i need 3 timezone in the same time

Comment: i use calgary,winnipeg,edmonton timezone

Comment: @DevGe would you like to show the same date in three different timezone? what is your actual requirement.

Comment: that 3 province has different time and date, so if i'm in edmonton then my configuration in timezone is for winnipeg, so it different to edmonton.

Comment: so how it may use the timezone of all city or province in canada.

Comment: there is an conflict happen if i set one timezone in my configuration

Comment: In such case better to save timezone in `UTC` in database so it would be consistent for all in application. And where you need to display the tmezone just parse that as per user current timezone.

Comment: Also I suggest to detect the usertimezone using javascript and capture in session... that will used to parse the timezone for display using Laravel Accessor. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: @DevGe let me know if it helps.

Comment: sorry , yeah it good suggestion but you give me idea about storing timezone of user in database. thanks anyway.